# Find a permutation $X \in S_6$ which satisfies the equation

Tags: functions, permutations, permutation-cycles, permutation-matrices

$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\ 4&3&1&5&2&6\end{pmatrix} \circ X = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\ 3&2&4&5&1&6\end{pmatrix}$

I've tried [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/549191/1112840) and [checked this website](https://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/permutations/permutations.html), but none of them were helpful or my problem is little bit different and may require more steps to get the solution. Could anybody help me sort this out?

Comment: Hint. Your life with permutations will be much easier if you learn cycle notation for permutations. (Look it up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\ 4&3&1&5&2&6\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\circ \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\ 3&2&4&5&1&6\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked out!

Comment: I'm glad to be inspiring, He-he : )

Comment: How would you calculate following equation?:

$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\ 3&1&5&2&4&6\end{pmatrix} \circ X \circ \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\ 2&5&3&6&1&4\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\ 1&2&4&3&6&5\end{pmatrix}$

I tried to find inverse of the first two permutations, then followed hint shown above, but I didn't get expected output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Being of the form $A\circ X\circ B=C$ then $X=A^{-1}\circ C\circ B^{-1}$.